# Android, Nested Transactions Not Working

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

Heloou, im trying to do a Nested Transaction, but is throwing SqliteDatabaseLockedException, and am not sure why...

the data sources open() method assign a Writable Database to their respective attributes, to later call methods to manipulate data. they both use a SQLHelpder to return a writableDatabase.

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {

            try {
                clientDataSource.open();
                movementDataSource.open();

                clientDataSource.getDatabase().beginTransaction();
                movementDataSource.getDatabase().beginTransaction();

                if(sendMovements()) {
                    movementDataSource.getDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
                    clientDataSource.deleteAllClients();
                }
                updateDatabase(url[0]);
                clientDataSource.getDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Treat Json Exception
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Treat IOException
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                movementDataSource.getDatabase().endTransaction();
                clientDataSource.getDatabase().endTransaction();
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: whats inside updateDatabase method?

Comment: i retrieve data from a server and insert new clients into the db

Comment: which db movementDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is form sqlite docs and here is what it says

Begins a transaction in EXCLUSIVE mode.

Transactions can be nested. When the outer transaction is ended all of the work done in that transaction and all of the nested transactions will be committed or rolled back. The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful). Otherwise they will be committed.

Here is the standard idiom for transactions:

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

so point is unless you mark your transaction end after calling it succesful, it will result in database locked error, and eventually this is what your doing.

movementDataSource.getDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful(); // After you call this, end this transaction otherwise it wil result in database locked error.

Comment: i tried ending the other transaction, still gives me the lock error

Comment: just for the record, WITHOUT the Transaction methods, it works Fine